# iTunes Store - Use My Credit Card Not Store Credit For A Gifted Item

Tags: itunes-store, gift

I have some store credit on my iTunes account that I got couple months ago and am gifting a film on iTunes for my sisters birthday..
If i gift the film does the cost come off my store credit or my credit card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from Apple's Support page about Gifting...

> "When you purchase an iTunes Gift, you must have a valid credit card
>   on file; you can't purchase an iTunes Gift with store credit..."
>   
>   - http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2736

So to simplify..

Apple charges the gifted item straight to your credit/debit card. **NOT** the credit on your account.